# Set a relative timeout threshold for a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, timeout, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

At some point when I was using Jenkins in the past, it was possible to set a relative timeout threshold (e.g. if the build takes 50% more time to complete than you fail it). Now it seems that the way to impose timeouts in a Jenkins Pipeline is to use the [timeout step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit). But I only saw a possibility to set absolute values, not a relative ones.

Is there a way to have a relative threshold in a Jenkins (declarative) pipeline?

Comment: "50% more time to complete" than what?

Comment: To be able to get 50% more time (than the previous build, I assume), your current build should be able to access the last build, because you need to get the "duration" of the build. AFAIK, that would cause security issues and therefore, is not allowed. Anyway, if you do not care about those issues, you should be able to do it by yourself: read the "duration" from the (let's say) last 3 builds, calculate its average and increase it with that 50%

Comment: @MaratC, if your last build (or e.g., last 5 builds on average) took 1 hour, and your next build takes 1 hour 30 minutes (or more), the job should fail

Comment: This functionality was provided by a plugin, not the Jenkins core, if memory serves. If you remember the name of that plugin, there could be a pipeline syntax for it. I don't unfortunately.

Comment: @Uko that's rather easy to calculate in the pipeline by walking over your last builds as suggested.